# How to rise dropdown menu over page content without js?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, drop-down-menu

The menu of my homepage includes a drop-down menu. I use html, css and php but no js. I cannot get the drop-down menu not to push down the content of the page, but to open over the content. Could you maybe have a look at it and tell me, how I could repair the code? Thanks in advance.

I tried it with z-index, I've read that with this I can lift one content over another one, just like layers, but it does not seem to react on it. Could you tell me, what is wrong with this?

```css
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 5px solid whitesmoke;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    align-items: start;    
}
.dropdown{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.dropbtn{
    flex-direction: row;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-content{
    display: none;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar flex">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn"><a href="./admin.php">Serv</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">"Meta"</a>
            <a href="#">VA</a>
            <a href="#">Admin</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="./oktatas.php">Okt</a>
    <a href="./va.php" id="ajanlat">Aj</a>
    <a href="./how.php">About</a>
    <a href="./admin.php">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) to the drop down menu. This property removes the element from the "normal" layout flow, and allows the element to overlay other elements on the page:

```css
.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 5px solid whitesmoke;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    align-items: start;    
}
.dropdown{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.dropbtn{
    flex-direction: row;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-content{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content a{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar flex">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn"><a href="./admin.php">Serv</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">"Meta"</a>
            <a href="#">VA</a>
            <a href="#">Admin</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="./oktatas.php">Okt</a>
    <a href="./va.php" id="ajanlat">Aj</a>
    <a href="./how.php">About</a>
    <a href="./admin.php">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

You can apply further CSS properties to position it how you'd like.